# Jquery plugin for tiered, indented select elements?

Tags: jquery, html

I tried doing it with the normal select but the fact that most browsers don't support ANY css styling on the options means i'm not going very far with that and I really don't have time to design my own.

What I'm trying to do is basically have a select for a folder structure that is tiered and have some kind of indent feature be it images (preferred so I can draw the relationships somehow) or padding or something of the sort.

I found some plugins already but none that support the kind of indenting I'm after.

Comment: If your folder structure is < 2 levels deep, you could maybe use optgroup

Comment: It's 4 levels deep and optgroup makes the group label unselectable so it doesn't really work for folder structures

Comment: What about just indent with characters. For instance "----| File #1"

Comment: That way it's gonna be "---| File #1" when it's selected and that looks ugly as hell. Same with &nbsp; indenting

Comment: Oke, then what about displaying radio buttons?

Comment: Not when there's tens of folders to display